# Oledb Read False Value From Excel Sheet

Tags: c#, winforms, oledb

I am trying to read Excel sheet which is **already opened** in window explorer using oledbReader with following code

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection mCon;
mCon.ConnectionString = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" + openFileDialog1.FileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1\";");
strSelectQuery = "SELECT TOP 20 * FROM [$Sheet1]";
        if (mCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            mCon.Open();
        }
        DataAdapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSelectQuery, mCon);
        DataAdapter.Fill(mDTable);
        DataAdapter.Dispose();
        mCon.Close();
```

Here it reads

```
 03-Aug-12 as 41124 // Excel Column has Genral format
 07:29:19 as 0.31202546296 //Excel Column has Genral format
 359307046362750 as 3.5930704636e+014 // Excel Column has Number Format with Decimal place 0
```

If the excel file is **closed** it reads the value in correct format.
Why it is doing so ?

Comment: Any Answer ??  Any clue ?? Still Waiting for some one to response ..

Comment: If you open a normal Excel and key the value 03-Aug-12 keeping General as the Number Format, it will automatically change the Number Format, but if again you try to set the format of the same cell to General you will find the result as 41124, it is an excel property..so it always preferred to set the Number Format to Text when working with Excel

Comment: @RohitAgrawal I have no rights to changes the excel. Is there any workaround for this to read correctly. Why it is reading well and good when file is closed ?

Comment: I Guess you should use the worksheet object and traverse through the rows and columns of excel to achieve this when worksheet is in open state instead of using OLEDB or set the NumberFormat of the entire sheet to Text format.